# How to programmatically fetch the results of a view with facet filtering

Tags: 8, views, search

**Setup**

- Drupal 8.2 + Views + Facets
- View `articles` …

  - … with first sub-view `page_1`
  - … has facets
- View filter: `field_title`
- View facet: `field_facet` allows multiple values, e.g. `A` and `B`

**Concept**

I would like to fetch the view results programmatically by reusing the `$_GET` query values. (The `$_GET` values are serialized and stored for later usage.)

**Problem**

The results are correct when working with only non-facet filters. Facet filter values are ignored and won't be filtering the results by the provided snippet.

**Is the View working as expected?**

Yes, the view is working as expected: Filtering works when visiting the website with a HTTP client and the query `?field_title=Hello&field_facet[0]=A&field_facet[1]=B`.

**Snippet**

```
<?php

use Drupal\views\Views;

$view = Views::getView('articles');

$query = [
    // Filters results with title `Hello` as expected.
    'field_title' => 'Hello',

    // The programatically executed View ignores
    // the following facet based values for filtering.
    'field_facet' => ['A', 'B'],
];

$view->setExposedInput($query);

// bool(true)
var_dump($view->execute('page_1'));

$result = [];

/** @var Drupal\views\ResultRow $row */
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
    /** @var Drupal\search_api\Item\Item $item */
    $item = $row->_item;

    /** @var Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
    $node = $item->getOriginalObject()->getValue();

    $result[] = [
        'nid' => $node->id(),
        'title ($item)' => $item->getField('title')->getValues()[0],
        'title ($node)' => $node->get('title')->getValue(),
    ];
}
```

**Experiments with the REST module**

The REST module allows to create views with JSON results.
Sadly, this module is also ignoring facet based filters.

**Question**

How do I inject/attach the facets to use their filters?

Answer (score 5):

Kinda old question but i just needed the same thing and here is how i did it.

```
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


$view_id = 'VIEWID';
$display_id = 'rest_export_1';
$filters = [
  // Filters results with title `Hello` as expected.
  'field_title' => 'Hello',

  // The programatically executed View ignores
  // the following facet based values for filtering.
  'field_facet' => ['A', 'B'],
];

$view = Views::getView($view_id);
$view->setDisplay($display_id);

// Here comes the part that did the trick for my REST JSON request.
// Create a new request with your filters / url query and set that.
$request = new Request($filters);
$view->setRequest($request);

$view->execute();

//TMP debug the json decoded value
$view_result = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($view->render());
$view_json_decode = json_decode($view_result);
```

The rest export view puts the exposed filter inside the view request so instead of setting the exposedfilters i made a request with the query args and it worked fine.

The documentation is missing a lot so if anyone finds a better way then let me know.