# When to filter search results with facets programmatically

Tags: views, search

To group search results and display them in different blocks i want to filter 
them programmatically with facets.

I found a [Solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230320/how-to-programmatically-fetch-the-results-of-a-view-with-facet-filtering),
where the view is executed only with a new request object.

term = searchword
content = facet field

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view__search_view__page(&$vars) {
    $view = Drupal\views\Views::getView('search_view_groups');
    $view->setDisplay('block_groups');

    $filters = [
        'term' => $vars['view']->getRequest()->query->get('term'),
        'content' => ['bereich:80']
    ];

    $request = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request($filters);
    $view->setRequest($request);
    $view->execute();

    dump($view->result);
    dump($view->getRequest());
}
```

The code works with params from the real request, but i can't change them in the hook. So i guess i use the wrong hook.

When should i run the filter? Which is the correct hook for that?

Setup:
Drupal: 8.3.5
facets: 1.x-dev
search_api: 1.3